# Foreign Key Association and Independent Association, Whose priority is higher?

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

If I have an entity in EF and I also have foreign key property in that entity. Now I want to update related record. If I use both  `Foreign Key Association` and `Independent Association`, Then which will be preferred by Entity Framework and why ?

**Case :** Suppose If I assign different entity to navigation property and different enityId in foreign key property. Then what will be saved in database ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the foreign key in your case. Independent key just for the table's itself